# Updating Popup.Animated to play gif until external task is completed (PYSimpleGUI)

Tags: python, animation, popup, pysimplegui

I am looking to create a UI that displays an animated popup while another task is being carried out. That will exit upon completion. I am using PYSimpleGUI and am using the example listed [here](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms%20old/Demo_Threaded_Work.py) to base my work off. I can get a single frame of the animation to display once I start the code and exit upon completion of the task but can't get it to play the entire gif. Code:

```
    import queue
    import threading
    import time
    import PySimpleGUI as sg

    # ############################# User callable CPU intensive code #############################
    # Put your long running code inside this "wrapper"
    # NEVER make calls to PySimpleGUI from this thread (or any thread)!
    # Create one of these functions for EVERY long-running call you want to make

    def long_function_wrapper(work_id, gui_queue):
      # LOCATION 1
      # this is our "long running function call"
      #time.sleep(10)  # sleep for a while as a simulation of a long-running computation

     x = 0
     while True:
         print(x)
         time.sleep(0.5)
         x = x + 1
         if x == 5: 
            break



    # at the end of the work, before exiting, send a message back to the GUI indicating end
    gui_queue.put('{} ::: done'.format(work_id))
    # at this point, the thread exits
    return

    def the_gui():
    gui_queue = queue.Queue()  # queue used to communicate between the gui and long-running code

    layout = [[sg.Text('Multithreaded Work Example')],
              [sg.Text('This is a Test.', size=(25, 1), key='_OUTPUT_')],
              [sg.Button('Go'), sg.Button('Exit')], ]



    window = sg.Window('Multithreaded Window').Layout(layout)


    # --------------------- EVENT LOOP ---------------------
    work_id = 0
    while True:
        event, values = window.Read(timeout=100)  # wait for up to 100 ms for a GUI event

        if event is None or event == 'Exit':
            #sg.PopupAnimated(None)
            break
        if event == 'Go':           # clicking "Go" starts a long running work item by starting thread
            window.Element('_OUTPUT_').Update('Starting long work %s'%work_id)


            # LOCATION 2
            # STARTING long run by starting a thread
            thread_id = threading.Thread(target=long_function_wrapper, args=(work_id, gui_queue,), daemon=True)
            thread_id.start()
            #for i in range(200000):

            work_id = work_id+1 if work_id < 19 else 0

            #while True:
            sg.PopupAnimated(sg.DEFAULT_BASE64_LOADING_GIF, background_color='white', time_between_frames=100)    
                #if message == None:
                    #break   
        # --------------- Read next message coming in from threads ---------------
        try:
            message = gui_queue.get_nowait()    # see if something has been posted to Queue

        except queue.Empty:                     # get_nowait() will get exception when Queue is empty
            message = None                      # nothing in queue so do nothing


        # if message received from queue, then some work was completed
        if message is not None:
            # LOCATION 3
            # this is the place you would execute code at ENDING of long running task
            # You can check the completed_work_id variable to see exactly which long-running function completed
            completed_work_id = int(message[:message.index(' :::')])
            sg.PopupAnimated(None)


        #window['_GIF_'].update_animation(sg.DEFAULT_BASE64_LOADING_GIF, time_between_frames=100)
        #window.read(timeout = 1000)

    # if user exits the window, then close the window and exit the GUI func
    window.Close()

    ############################# Main #############################

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        the_gui()
        print('Exiting Program'

)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got your call to popup_animated inside of an "if" statement that is only executed once.

You must call popup_animated for every frame you wish to show.  It's not spun off as a task that works in the background.

This change to your code will keep the animation going as long as there as background tasks running.

```py
import queue
import threading
import time
import PySimpleGUI as sg


# ############################# User callable CPU intensive code #############################
# Put your long running code inside this "wrapper"
# NEVER make calls to PySimpleGUI from this thread (or any thread)!
# Create one of these functions for EVERY long-running call you want to make

def long_function_wrapper(work_id, gui_queue):
    # LOCATION 1
    # this is our "long running function call"
    # time.sleep(10)  # sleep for a while as a simulation of a long-running computation

    x = 0
    while True:
        print(x)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        x = x + 1
        if x == 5:
            break
    # at the end of the work, before exiting, send a message back to the GUI indicating end
    gui_queue.put('{} ::: done'.format(work_id))
    # at this point, the thread exits
    return


def the_gui():


    gui_queue = queue.Queue()  # queue used to communicate between the gui and long-running code

    layout = [[sg.Text('Multithreaded Work Example')],
              [sg.Text('This is a Test.', size=(25, 1), key='_OUTPUT_')],
              [sg.Text(size=(25, 1), key='_OUTPUT2_')],
              [sg.Button('Go'), sg.Button('Exit')], ]

    window = sg.Window('Multithreaded Window').Layout(layout)

    # --------------------- EVENT LOOP ---------------------
    work_id = 0
    while True:
        event, values = window.Read(timeout=100)  # wait for up to 100 ms for a GUI event

        if event is None or event == 'Exit':
            # sg.PopupAnimated(None)
            break
        if event == 'Go':  # clicking "Go" starts a long running work item by starting thread
            window.Element('_OUTPUT_').Update('Starting long work %s' % work_id)
            # LOCATION 2
            # STARTING long run by starting a thread
            thread_id = threading.Thread(target=long_function_wrapper, args=(work_id, gui_queue,), daemon=True)
            thread_id.start()
            # for i in range(200000):

            work_id = work_id + 1 if work_id < 19 else 0

            # while True:
            # if message == None:
            # break
        # --------------- Read next message coming in from threads ---------------
        try:
            message = gui_queue.get_nowait()  # see if something has been posted to Queue
        except queue.Empty:  # get_nowait() will get exception when Queue is empty
            message = None  # nothing in queue so do nothing
        # if message received from queue, then some work was completed
        if message is not None:
            # LOCATION 3
            # this is the place you would execute code at ENDING of long running task
            # You can check the completed_work_id variable to see exactly which long-running function completed
            completed_work_id = int(message[:message.index(' :::')])
            window.Element('_OUTPUT2_').Update('Finished long work %s' % completed_work_id)
            work_id -= 1
            if not work_id:
                sg.PopupAnimated(None)

        if work_id:
            sg.PopupAnimated(sg.DEFAULT_BASE64_LOADING_GIF, background_color='white', time_between_frames=100)

        # window['_GIF_'].update_animation(sg.DEFAULT_BASE64_LOADING_GIF, time_between_frames=100)
        # window.read(timeout = 1000)

    # if user exits the window, then close the window and exit the GUI func
    window.Close()

############################# Main #############################

if __name__ == '__main__':
    the_gui()
    print('Exiting Program')
```